# Dynamic queries in Spring Data JPA. Refactoring

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Working with Spring data jpa and specifications, I have a requirement to implement a filter/search feature in spring mvc.  The backend receives an object (ReportTemplateBean) which is basically a bean with some fields that represents the filters in the front end.

```
public class ReportTemplateBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3915391620260021813L;

private Long id;

private String property;

private String city;

private String state;

private String zipCode;

private String propertyStatus;

private String realEstateRep;
//more code
```

We have the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ReportBean search(@AuthenticationPrincipal ActiveUser activeUser,
    @ModelAttribute("templateForm") ReportTemplateBean template,
    Pageable pageable) throws GenericException {
LOGGER.info("Pulling report requested");

ReportBean report = reportService.searchProperties(template,
    pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize());

return report;
}
```

The service

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 20)
public ReportBean searchProperties(ReportTemplateBean template,
    Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) throws GenericException,
    TransactionTimedOutException {
LOGGER.info("searchProperties({})", template);

try {
    // pageNumber = (pageNumber == null ? 0 : pageNumber);
    // pageSize = (pageSize == null ? 10 : pageSize);
    ReportTemplate t = reportTemplateMapper.beanToEntity(template);
    List<PropertyBean> beans = new ArrayList<PropertyBean>();
    PropertySpecification spec = new PropertySpecification(t);
    Page<Property> properties = propertyRepository.findAll(spec,
        new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.Direction.ASC,
            "name"));
```

And then it builds the query dynamically, but using a long IF chain that I don't like it.  This is the Specification.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Property> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
    CriteriaBuilder cb) {
Path<String> propertyName = root.get(Property_.name);
Path<String> city = root.get(Property_.city);
Path<String> state = root.get(Property_.state);
Path<String> zipCode = root.get(Property_.zipCode);
final List<Predicate> orPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
final List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if (template.getProperty() != null
    && template.getProperty().length() > 0) {
    andPredicates.add(cb.equal(propertyName, template.getProperty()));
}
if (template.getCity() != null && template.getCity().length() > 0) {
    andPredicates.add(cb.equal(city, template.getCity()));
}
if (template.getState() != null && template.getState().length() > 0) {
    andPredicates.add(cb.equal(state, template.getState()));
}
if (template.getZipCode() != null && template.getZipCode().length() > 0) {
    andPredicates.add(cb.equal(zipCode, template.getZipCode()));
}
if (template.getRealEstateRep() != null) {
    Join<Property, User> pu = null;
    if (query.getResultType().getName().equals("java.lang.Long")) {
    pu = (Join<Property, User>) root.fetch(Property_.createdBy);
    } else {
    pu = root.join(Property_.createdBy);
    }
    Path<Long> userId = pu.get(User_.id);
    andPredicates.add(cb.equal(userId, template.getRealEstateRep()));
}
if (template.getProjectType() != null
    && template.getProjectType().length() > 0) {
    Join<Property, Project> pp = null;
    if (query.getResultType().getName().equals("java.lang.Long")) {
    pp = root.join(Property_.projects);
    } else {
    pp = (Join<Property, Project>) root.fetch(Property_.projects);
    }
    Path<String> projectType = pp.get(Project_.projectName);
    andPredicates.add(cb.equal(projectType, template.getProjectType()));
}
//more IF's
return query.getRestriction();
}
```

As you can notice the Specification seems ugly and besides that SONAR complains about The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method  (which is good).

So question is, How can I refactor the Specification (IF's) to be more OO code?.
Thanks in advance.
**UPDATE**- I would like to use/implement something like the new feature in Spring Data JPA ([Query by Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#query-by-example.execution))  It seems that if you pass a bean the *ExampleMatcher* class will ignore the null value in the bean fields which is almost what I am looking for.  Ignore null and empty values.

Comment: Do you want a solution only using Specification? I had a similar problem, but i solved it writing the query with @Query annotation with optional parameters in my repository

Comment: Would be nice using Specification but not mandatory, can I take a look on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I write my solution to give you another option, but as i say in the comment i do not used Specification, and i am curious to see if anyone knows another way to do dynamic queries in spring jpa.

You could write your own query with the `@Query` annotation inside a `@Repository` interface. 
In your case (assuming *ReportTemplateBean* is your Entity and its primary key is of *Long* type) it would be like:

```
@Repository
public interface ReportTemplateRepo extends JpaRepository<ReportTemplateBean, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT rb FROM ReportBeanTemplate rb JOIN ExampleTable et WHERE et.idTemplate = rb.id AND (:id is null OR :id = rb.id) AND (:city is null OR :city = rb.city) AND (:state is null OR :state = rb.state)")
    public List<ReportTemplateBean> findTemplates(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("city") String city, @Param("state") String state);
}
```

You can add all the parameters you want, pass it as null when you call the method.

Example of method invocation(in you service class):

```
@Autowire
ReportTemplateRepo templateRepo;

public void invocation(ReportTemplateBean template){
    List<ReportTemplateBean> templateRepo.findTemplates(
        template.getId(), template.getCity(), template.getState());
    }
```

This is the only way i found to do this kind of query.

Comment: What about if you have relationships? i mean, my bean has OneToOne and OneToMany relationships.  Does your solution can manage this? How manage then when is null? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tested, because i still don't have OneToMany relationship in my project, but take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614247/default-sort-on-a-spring-data-jpa-repository-method-with-custom-query-and-pageab. He uses relationship and query with dynamic parameters and he says that it works. But i don't know how to manage this kind of relationship when is null